# noexcept specifier with default arguments construction

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, noexcept

Take the following example code:

```
void test(const Item& item = Item()) {
   ...
}
```

Assume that, once `item` has been passed to the function, this cannot throw.

The question is: the function should be marked `noexcept` or `noexcept(noexcept(Item()))`?

IHMO, the former should be ok, but I am not sure. A quotation from the standard would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Default arguments are shortcut notations for the caller of function. So, when the function executes, the construction is already complete.

Thus, `noexcept` should be sufficient.

In the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) [dcl.fct.default] states:

> If an initializer-clause is specified in a parameter-declaration this
>   initializer-clause is used as a default argument. Default arguments will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing.
>
> Example:
>   the declaration
>   `void point(int = 3, int = 4);`
>   declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two arguments of type int. It can be called in
>   any of these ways:
>   `point(1,2);`  `point(1);`  `point();`
>   The last two calls are equivalent to
>   `point(1,4)` and `point(3,4)` , respectively.

Also there is a note (in [intro.execution] Program execution):

> Subexpressions involved in evaluating default arguments (8.3.6) are
>   considered to be created in the expression that calls the function, not the expression that defines the default
>   argument

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Can you find something (even from cppreference would be ok) to prove that? My doubts are related to noexcept forwarding: if this function is noexcept, noexcept(test) would be true, but it would be misleading from a caller point of view.

Comment: @dodomorandi From the language, the caller has already created the arguments. The noexcept specifier is only for the function itself. That the construction might throw is therefore not relevant for the function itself.

Comment: That note is gone from the latest draft :(

Comment: I accepted you answer because you perfectly replied my question. However, I am editing the question because I thought about a case that I would like you to comment, if you want.

Comment: @Rakete1111 The note is from "1.9 Program execution" in the linked PDF of the draft that I was using.

Comment: @PhilippClaßen ok, what I was trying to do was to get the noexcept state of a wrapper function. What I always forget is that the type default parameter cannot be omitted in a `decltype` expression -- therefore there should not be a way to get a misleading `noexcept` value from generic code. If I am wrong, please let me know.

Comment: This is correct, but I'll point out that Herb Sutter once strongly advised against a similar case (passing a type whose copy c'tor may throw – by value), because it can easily mislead the caller, as dodomorandi pointed out. On the other hand, `noexcept(Item())` is stricter than required when the argument has already been constructed. This may be another case of "default arguments considered harmful" and I recommend using two overloads instead.

Comment: I think the normative text is in [\[expr.call\]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#7.sentence-5). cc @Rakete1111